# "Bad Request" response on Tumblr's API "quote" request

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I develope a PHP script that uses Tumblr's API. When I post a "text" everything works fine, but on "quote" posts I get a "Bad Request" error. I use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to get the "tumblr/tumblr" repository from https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php.

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$consumer_key = 'KEY';
$consumer_secret = 'SECRET';
$token = 'TOKEN';
$token_secret = 'SECRET';
$blog = 'BLOG';

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $token_secret);

#$options = array('type' => 'text', 'title' => 'Title', 'body' => 'Body', 'tags' => 'Test');
$options = array('type' => 'quote', 'text' => 'Text', 'source' => 'Source', 'tags' => 'Test');

try{
    $res = $client->createPost($blog, $options);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use a API inspector tool like Fiddler, Charles or Runscope to see the actual HTTP request/response going back and forth. That will help narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting), the quote type requires a **`"quote"`** field instead of a `"text"` field.

Change your parameters to this and it should work:

```
$options = array('type' => 'quote', 'quote' => 'Text', 'source' => 'Source', 'tags' => 'Test');
```

Granted, it looks like the `Tumblr\API\RequestException` doesn't return a helpful error message. I was able to figure this out by hacking `Tumblr\API\RequestException` and putting a `var_dump` in the constructor:

```
public function __construct($response)
{
    $error = json_decode($response->body);
    var_dump($error->response);
    ...
```

With that, I was at least able to get a good error message:

```
class stdClass#668 (1) {
  public $errors =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(21) "Post cannot be empty."
  }
}
```

Comment: Aw man, yes of course. Thx very much!!! It works! :)
It only return a helpful error message if you don't catch the exception.